# Find all User's UserID in a server

Tags: python, discord

How would I find and store all of the users UserID's in a discord server?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith("##kickrandom"):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Kicking a random user in 30 seconds...")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each user only has 1 ID, so you can get a full list of members on the server and grab the ID of each

```
ids = []
for m in server.members:
    ids.append(m.id)
```

Python has a tool to do this quickly called list compression.

```
ids = [m.id for m in server.members]
```

However, if you just want to kick a random member, you can just use

```
target = random.choice(list(server.members))
```