# Getting Member of a discord server given server id

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create a script that given a server id, it should return all the member of that discord server.
and given a user authentification token, it should check if he is a member of that server.

I have been looking how to do this but in vain!
I have tried those 3 questions but they don't give me any information on what I want to do.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733376/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-all-members-in-a-discord-server-using-discord-py)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689289/joining-a-server-with-the-discord-python-api)

[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732711/find-all-users-userid-in-a-server)

Here is what i have tried  according to the documentation and get started tutorial:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import os


client = discord.Client()
email  = os.getenv('Email')
password = os.getenv('Password')
server = discord.Server(id='416940353564704768')
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')
    print('get all channel a client belong to ')
    if server.members:
        for member in server.members:
            print('name{}'.format(member.user.name) )
    else:
        print('any')

client.run(email, password)
```

But it always prints any.
Any helps will be appreciated, it looks like I'm missing something on how discord works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A couple things to point out:

- You need to get the server from the client. You can't just do `discord.Server(id="111111")`. Instead, use the get_server method. `client.get_server(id="11111")`.
- Put the `get_server` method in the `on_ready` event. This ensures the `client` is connected to discord and has received its server list and all other data.
- A `Member` object is just a subclass of `User`; therefore, you can't do `Member.user.name` because neither `Member` nor `User` have a `user` property. You only need to do `Member.name`.
- Lastly, I wouldn't recommend you to use a self bot. That is, using your own discord account as though it were a bot. You should use an actual bot account with its token.

Ultimately, your code should look like this.

```
import discord
import asyncio
import os

client = discord.Client()
email  = os.getenv('Email')
password = os.getenv('Password')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    server = client.get_server(id="416940353564704768")
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')
    print('get all channel a client belong to ')
    if server:
        for member in server.members:
            print('name: {}'.format(member.name) )
    else:
        print('any')

client.run(email, password)
```

As for your second question, I'm not sure what you mean by **"given a user authentification token, it should check if he is a member of that server."**. If you're given their login token, I don't exactly know how you'd use that to check if they're in a sever without logging into that account. And if you *do* plan on logging in to the account, I believe you'll need to do that in a separate script. However, you can easily check if the logged in client is in a server:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    server = discord.utils.get(client.servers, id="416940353564704768")
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

    if server:
        print("Client is a member of: {}".format(server.name))
    else:
        print("Client is not a member")
```